# How to correctly reorder array when using computed properties with SortableJS and Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, sortablejs

I have an `array` of elements, but i want to display it and provide a **Draggable** feature ([SortableJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable)) but only a part of that `array`.

To do that i used a computed property from the original data array and split the array in two arrays, i used these computed arrays to make a list, but when i drag and try to reorder the list dragging it seems like there is something wrong with indexes, like the example down below, if you try to drag the first list, it will not reorder, but the second one will.

So how can i solve this issue?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { draggable: window.vuedraggable },
  data: () => {
    return {
      numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    evens() {
      return this.numbers.filter(number => number % 2 === 0);
    },
    odds() {
      return this.numbers.filter(number => number % 2 === 1);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@1.8.4/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Vue.Draggable/2.20.0/vuedraggable.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <ul style="width: 50%">
      <draggable v-model="numbers"
        draggable="li">
        <transition-group type="transition">
          <template v-for="(number, index) in evens">
            <li :key="index">{{ number }}</li>
          </template>
        </transition-group>
      </draggable>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <template v-for="number in odds">
        <li>{{ number }}</li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `draggable`'s `v-model` (i.e., `numbers`) and the elements being rendered inside the `draggable` (i.e., `evens`) are two different data sets. When you reorder `evens` by dragging its 3 items, `draggable` is reordering the first 3 items in `numbers`, as those items have the same indices in the two data sets.

One workaround to ensure that the list order is preserved is to render the full list of `numbers` but [`v-show`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show) only the even numbers:

```html
<draggable v-model="numbers">
  <template v-for="(number, index) in numbers">
    <li v-show="number % 2 === 0" :key="number">{{ number }}</li>
  </template>
</draggable>
```

Note when a rendered list can be reordered, don't use `index` as the `key`, as that wouldn't be unique between moved items, causing rendering issues (reusing an element unintentionally). I've used `number` above, as that's suitably unique in this case.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { draggable: window.vuedraggable },
  data: () => {
    return {
      numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    odds() {
      return this.numbers.filter(number => number % 2 === 1);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@1.8.4/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Vue.Draggable/2.20.0/vuedraggable.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <ul style="width: 50%">
      <draggable v-model="numbers"
        draggable="li">
        <transition-group type="transition">
          <template v-for="(number, index) in numbers">
            <li v-show="number % 2 === 0" :key="number">{{ number }}</li>
          </template>
        </transition-group>
      </draggable>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <template v-for="number in odds">
        <li>{{ number }}</li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <pre>numbers: {{numbers}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically there is no a good way to do what i'm trying to do? Only having two different arrays? Because the point was to use the two computed arrays and reorder in the correct order when i use drag on each of the two list of arrays of the computed arrays, i just didn't put in the code because i thought wasn't relevant.